# Convert YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssTZD format date string to local time

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime

In my spring boot application I have to convert ISO 8601 datetime to localdatetime without using JODA. Currently what I am doing is

```
String receivedDateTime = "2019-11-13T00:11:08+05:00";

ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse(receivedDateTime);

DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
        utcFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date date = new Date();
        try {
            date = utcFormat.parse(zonedDateTime.toString());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

When I am using receivedDateTime  with +00:00 like "2019-11-13T00:11:08+00:00" then it does not give any parsing error but not converting either. When I use +01:00 at the end then it also gives the parsing error.

**UPDATE: 1**

As per @Deadpool answer, I am using it like

```
String receivedDateTime  = "2019-11-13T00:11:08+05:00";

        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
                .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HH:MM", "+00:00").optionalEnd()
                .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HHMM", "0000").optionalEnd()
                .toFormatter();

        OffsetDateTime dt = OffsetDateTime.parse(receivedDateTime, formatter);
        LocalDateTime ldt = dt.toLocalDateTime();

        System.out.println(ldt);
```

and the the value of **ldt** it print is **2019-11-13T00:11:08**.

**UPDATE 2:**
I tried using C# the same example and it gives me this date time **{2019-11-12 11:11:08 AM}**, which looks correct as the input time GMT +5 Hours and local time is EST America. So, when it converted it then it went back to 12th of Nov. Here is the code

```
var timeString = "2019-11-13T00:11:08+05:00";
DateTime d2 = DateTime.Parse(timeString, null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!" + d2);
```

**UPDATE 3:** So it boils down to following solution input String "2019-11-13T06:01:41+00:00" and output is local date "2019-11-13T00:01:41" Where system defauld ZoneId is "America/Chicago" which is -06:00 GMT

```
private LocalDateTime convertUtcStringToLocalDateTime(String UtcDateTime) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
                .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HH:MM", "+00:00").optionalEnd()
                .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HHMM", "0000").optionalEnd()
                .toFormatter();

        OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(UtcDateTime, formatter);
        return dateTime.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of(ZoneId.systemDefault().getId())).toLocalDateTime();
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you are using `ZonedDateTime.parse` to then convert it back to a string and parse it with  a `SimpleDateFormat`. Where's the `LocalDateTime`?

Comment: When you can use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, stick to that and avoid the old and troublesome classes `SimpleDateFormat`, `DateFormat`, `TimeZone` and `Date`. The modern API gives you all the functionality you need. Mixing old and modern just adds extra complication with no gain.

Comment: @OleV.V. I agree with you. Do you have better solution than UPDATE 3 then please share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using java.time alone this is simpler than you seem to think:

```
    String receivedDateTime = "2019-11-13T00:11:08+05:00";

    OffsetDateTime parsedDateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(receivedDateTime);
    ZonedDateTime dateTimeInMyTimeZone
            = parsedDateTime.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault());
    System.out.println(dateTimeInMyTimeZone);
```

When I ran this in America/Toronto time zone, the output was:

> 2019-11-12T14:11:08-05:00[America/Toronto]

Since your string contains an offset, `+05:00`, and no time zone, like `Asia/Karachi`, use an `OffsetDateTime` for parsing it. Then convert to your local time zone using the `atZoneSameInstant` method. Even though you asked for your local time, don’t be fooled into using `LocalDateTime`.  That class represent a date and time *without any time zone*, which is not what you need (and seldom needed at all).

Fortunately it’s easy to avoid the old classes `SimpleDateFormat`, `DateFormat`, `TimeZone` and `Date`. They were always poorly designed, the first two in particular are notoriously troublesome. They are all long outdated now. Instead get all the functionality we dream of from java.time, the modern Java date and time API.

### What happened in your code?

Don’t use `'Z'` in a format pattern string (and I repeat, don’t use `SimpleDateFormat`).

No matter if you use `ZonedDateTime` or `OffsetDateTime`, when you use `toString` with offset zero (as parsed from `+00:00`), the offset is printed as `Z`, which matches the `'Z'` in your format pattern string, so your second parsing works. Only parsing once, converting back to string and parsing again is needlessly complicated. Worse when the original offset was `+01:00` or `+05:00`. These are rendered the same again from `toString`, so don’t match `'Z'`, which caused your `ParseException`. *Never* use `'Z'` in a format pattern string. `Z` denotes an offset of zero and needs to be parsed as an offset for you to get the correct result.

Comment: Thanks @Ole.V.V., This solution is concise and clear

Answer (score 1):

By using `DateTimeFormatter` you can customize the date format with different `offset` format by making them optional

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
            .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HH:MM", "+00:00").optionalEnd()
            .optionalStart().appendOffset("+HHMM", "0000").optionalEnd()
            .toFormatter();
```

And the use the [OffsetDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) to parse string representing with offset

> A date-time with an offset from UTC/Greenwich in the ISO-8601 calendar system, such as 2007-12-03T10:15:30+01:00.

```
OffsetDateTime dateTime =  OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-11-13T00:11:08+0000", formatter);

OffsetDateTime dateTime =  OffsetDateTime.parse("2019-11-13T00:11:08+05:00", formatter);
```

If you want to convert it into local time zone time `LocalDateTime` then use `atZoneWithSameInstant()`

```
LocalDateTime local = dateTime.atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/New_York")).toLocalDateTime()
```

**Note :** Don't use `SimpleDateFormat` and `util.Date` which are legacy old framework

Comment: Thanks Deadpool, it printed 
2019-11-13T00:11:08Z
2019-11-13T00:11:08+05:00

Did I miss something? coz I tried it to convert it to local time

Comment: check the updated answer just call `toLocalDateTime()` @Karan

Comment: strange enough. it is giving me "2019-11-13T00:11:08" for the input string "2019-11-13T00:11:08+05:00". It cant be right

I am using it like this:
OffsetDateTime dt = OffsetDateTime.parse(receivedDateTime, formatter);
LocalDateTime ldt = dt.toLocalDateTime();

Comment: What is your expected outout? What are you expecting in local date ? @Karan

Comment: I think It's +5 hours of 00:11:08 so the local time should be different then that. Not exactly the same. I might be wrong

Comment: Please see update 2 and thats the reason I was thinking that in Java it was not the right answer

Comment: Nothing is impossible, try my updated solution if needed change the timezone that you want to convert @Karan

Comment: I believe that your formatter and in particular the optional offsets are unneeded complications. `OffsetDateTime` parses the string without any explicit formatter, both with `+05:00`, `+00:00` and `+01:00` in the string (I didn’t downvote).